# Is it possible to create relations between two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about two or more tabels in MySQL with relations. For college I need to create a form where people can fill in their:

```
Firstname
Lastname
Street and Housenumber
ZIPcode and City
State
Phonenumber
E-mail
Experience
Resume
(sendbutton)
```

Now I will create a admin panel where the admin can search people by state or city. How can I make a relation between those in the form and mysql? I do know a bit how relations work. I have a other site there someone can select a musicartist(tabel1) and after selecting the artist more information about the person will appear(tabel2) How can I do the same to my form I am creating?

Sorry for my bad english first, I hope it is clear enough to understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. First let know what you did yet.

Comment: Nothing at this moment I have to make a database design (before starting with programming) with atleast two relations. So I have to tell what I will use for words and numbers ( varchar-int ) those kinda thing. I already made this. But now I have to make a design where I can show my teacher the relations between The person/city/state. So when state is selected the persons from all cities in the state will show up... If city is selected al the persons will show up. I know how to do this with one tabel where everything is in but not when different tabels and relations

Comment: Ok, do start with coding and then ask help if get stuck at any point. Right now without any code or your work done, could not help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split your db up into entities. The only entities that catch the eye here are "Person" and "Address"

Using your attributes, split them into:

Person:

```
Firstname
Lastname
E-mail
Phonenumber
Experience
Resume
```

Address:

```
Street 
Housenumber
ZIPcode 
City
State
```

The idea is to spearate different data and group similar data. Now to add the relation, you need an id column in each table to make it 3nf. Then add another id to one of the tables to use as a foreign key.

I would add an attribute called "AddressId" to the person table and then use this attribute in a join on person.addressId = address.id. This will give you a one to many relationship where each Person has a single address but an address can have one multiple people associated with it.

You could do this a number of different ways as there is no real requirement other than forcing a relationship between tables. This would be the most common best practice, splitting the tables into logical divisions,but you could in theory take any of these attributes and make them a separate table.

Comment: Wow! great idea didn't think of this. But I think I will use this thank you very much!

Comment: no problem, glad to help out :)